# Login screen to UITabBarController missing navigation links

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

My login screen is embedded in a Navigation Controller.
Once user logs in with correct credentials, I want to push the user to the UITabBarController. I am able to do this, but when I go to different views by clicking on the tabs, then the individual views don't have any navigation buttons appearing.

In app delegate, once login is successful I am using the following code:

```
let myStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)

let protectedPage = myStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainView") as! UITabBarController

let protectedPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: protectedPage)

self.window?.rootViewController = protectedPageNav
```

How can I solve this?

[image: story board]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Apple documentation states you should preferably assign UITabBarController as root of UIWindow.

So change your code.

```
let myStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)

let protectedPage = myStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainView") as! UITabBarController


//change UIViewAnimationOptions enum value and you will get some animation
UIView.transition(with: self.window!, duration: 0.34, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.window?.rootViewController = protectedPage
        }, completion: {competion in

        })
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a ton!!